# Create letters, contract templates with rich text, save then in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, asp.net, rich-text-editor

I need to dev a web app that permits users create or write their own templates for letters, contracts, or mails.

This templates must be written with Rich Text Formatted on a user interface like stack overflow use.

The user can use some names columns of a SQL Server table or view, to insert then in the text, similar what MS Word do.

Documents must be saved in a SQL table and then that text must be use to create the final view this the data of the related field.

Example:

Columns of table `clients`:

```
clientId   Name   ProductName
-----------------------------
    1      Cris    Tablet
```

Letter created by user:

```
Hello dear *Name*
We've send you your *ProductName*
Sincerly
My Company
```

Final view in html:

```
Hello dear Cris
We've send you your Tablet
Sincerly
My Company
```

I've work with asp.net and SQL Server...  What do you recommend to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using C#, i doubt if SQL alone can do it, which language are you using in asp.net?If it is C#, I can explain.

Comment: Hello i'm using c# and sql server for database

Comment: @SolaOshinowo This should be a comment. It is not appropriate as an answer, please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

First 
On the User login page
After Each user as logged on
On the Button Onclick event
            Session["user"] = username.Text;
            Response.Redirect("nameofthepagetocreateletter");

Second(To create the letter template)
On the nameofthepagetocreateletter
 page_load event 
       loginname.Text = Session["user"].ToString();

also you will have a text control named "loginname", as well as 5 text field to write the letter

First text field-this will have its default value set to "Hello dear"
Second text field-this is the loginname
Third text field-this will have its default value set to "We've send you your"
Fourth text field-this is the product name field
Label field- this can be set as "sincerely"
Fifth text field-this is company name

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... But i have some question... how the user create the letter or document? how do you recoment store that letter? i'm looking from something similiar to phpdocx...  Even i'm thinking its an option to manage the documents with PHP...